# Keyboard Shortcut to Surround Selection with HTML Tag

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Desired Steps:

1. Highlight (select) HTML/text, e.g. `really`
2. Press keyboard shortcut
3. Highlighted text becomes `<b>really</b>`

How to?

Answer (score 0):

In a Javadoc comment you can just select the text which you want to wrap in a `<b>` tag and press CTRL+Space. Select the `<b>` template, press Enter and the selected text gets surrounded as expected. There are pre-defined templates for `<b>`, `<code>`, `<i>` and `<pre>`. You can define your own templates here: Java -> Editor -> Templates.

Comment: This is only possible in Javadoc comments? I was thinking more along the lines of when writing HTML.

Comment: This also depends on the editor you are using. Right click your .html file and select Open with... -> HTML Editor. Here you can select a word, press CTRL+1 and choose "Sourround with new element". Hm, in Eclipse 2019-03 this adds a line feed after the ending tag which is not what I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Quick Fix/Quick Assist: **Ctrl**/**Cmd**+**1**. Then start typing the tag name.

Comment: Trying to cut down on the number of steps to just the above 3, and as Kai mentioned, Quick Fix adds weird formatting and whitespace.